# How fast would an observer have to travel in order to be able to study an entire star's life in one human lifetime?

Tags: star, general-relativity, stellar-evolution, time-dilation

Humans live for about 80 years. A star, however, lives from 1 million to trillions of years, depending on its mass. If humans want to have a detailed study of the life of a $1 M_\odot$ star, how fast would they have to travel, and would it be viable?

Answer (score 1):

We want it so that $1 \text{ year at the speed of x% of c} = \dfrac{10^{10}}{80} \text{ stationary years}$. The Lorentz factor (in terms of c) is $\gamma=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$. Solving for $v$ with $\gamma =  \dfrac{10^{10}}{80},$ we get  $v=0.999999999999999968c = 299792457.999... \text{m}\cdot\text{s}^{-1}$. This is definitely impossible, as the energy requirements are astronomically large: $$5572282108577709241 \text{J}\cdot c^{-2} \cdot 125000000 =696535263572213655125000000 \text{J} = 7.75 \cdot 10^9 \text{ kg of mass converted to energy}$$

This is definitely unrealistic, and is a probably impossible feat to complete. It would be better to study more and more stars instead of exploiting time dilation to view a single star for billions of years.

Comment: How do you travel that fast *and* stay anywhere near the star you want to study? Or if not staying near it, how do you study it given the redshift the speed implies.

Comment: While the answer is right, the energy demands do not rule it out (one can in principle imagining an advanced civilization wasting massive resources on it). A better implausibility argument is that the blueshift of the CMB turns it into gamma rays, and they will brake the craft even if they do not fry it.